# CPU spikes on PDF render in PyQt and then freezes

Tags: python, mysql, pdf, pyqt

At one point, my application queries the MySQL database, and fetches 300 rows with this code:

```
cur.execute('''
    select 
        ime, brPredmeta, statusStr, sudskiBr, sudija,
        datumRasprave,statusPredmeta, zaduzen,datumZaduzenja
    from predmeti
    order by ime
    ''')
for row in cur: #extract data from variables
    ime, brPredmeta, statusStr, sudskiBr, sudija, datumRasprave, statusPredmeta, zaduzen, datumZaduzenja = row
```

`print(row)` shows the tuple in console window almost instantly. After data extraction, I use simple HTML to create 3 sections of PDF page; header, body and footer. All 3 are a simpe tables with 8-10 columns. Body however has 300 rows, since I'm appending them like this:

```
#we are still in FOR LOOP that iterates rows in cursor
body = ('<html><head><title></title>'
    '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>'
    '<style></style>'
    '</head>'
    '<body>'
    '<table align ="center" border="0" width="100%" style="table-layout:fixed">'
    '<tr height="10%">'
    '<td align="left" width="20">'+str(brojac)+'.</td>'
    '<td align="left" width="180">'+ime+'</td>'
    '<td align="left" width="100">'+str(brPredmeta)+'</td>'
    '<td align="left" width="80">'+statusStr+'</td>'
    '<td align="left" width="80">'+str(sudskiBr)+'</td>'
    '<td align="left" width="140">'+sudija+'</td>'
    '<td align="left" width="150">'+zaduzen+'</td>'
    '<td align="left">'+datumZaduzenja+'</td>'
    '<td align="right"> '+statusPredmeta+' </td>'
    '</tr>')

  self.ui.printHTML.append(body)
```

This EXACT SAME code was working without a hitch with SQLite. Since I switched to MySQL today it just freezes my whole program. CPU spikes to 100% (4 core i3) and RAM usage goes above 100MB (from 24MB at startup). After a minute I terminated the process.

When I use this function with other parameters (query differs a little) which produce less rows (from 60 - 120) everything goes smoothly.

**If I skip the "Print preview" dialog, and just print the PDF directly, everything works fine, no freezes, no nothing.**

I will add any additional info you might need. Thank you for reading.

Comment: Am I missing something or are you creating a full HTML (with `<html>`, `<body>`, etc.) with a table having single row for _each_ record in the database? And what type is `self.ui.printHTML`?

Comment: Yes, full HTML page, and it's body is a table with as many rows as query returns.

`self.ui.printHTML` is a `QTextEdit` element. This is the only way I am able to print on paper or PDF. Result looks something like this: [image](http://imgur.com/7KlSY)

Comment: _"it's body is a table with as many rows as query returns."_ It doesn't look like that from the code you pasted. You'll have separate tables with one row (actually separate `<html><body><table>`) for _each_ record.

Comment: You are right, I have edited the question. Still, I have the same problem with edited code - CPU usage is 100%, currently more than 100MB of RAM is being used and program froze. All I see is a blank "Print preview" dialog.